Predicting a time series containing two periodic components
I am modeling a family of systems whose output is the sum of two time series with different periods.
Consider two stationary processes $X_{1i}$ and $X_{2i}$. From this, I generate a time series for system ${i}$: $$x_i[n] \sim X_{i1} + X_{i2}  \text{ if } n\bmod N_i = 0 , \text{else } x_i[n] \sim X_{1i}$$
So, the samples always come from one time series, and another time series adds to it periodically. $N_i$ are unknown and change between different systems, but I know that each system has some periodic adder component $X_{2i}$. If it helps, some upper bound on $\{N_i\}$ may be assumed.
I want to deploy one algorithm that can handle any one of the whole family of systems. The algorithm gets the time series $x[n]$ from one system, without knowing $i$ and predicts the next value $x[n+1]$.
Is there a way to predict $x_i[n]$ without explicitly finding $N_i$ for the system using autocorrelation?
Ideally looking for some ARMA/ARIMA type model for this problem. This looks like a seasonal time series with unknown seasonality. Tried to handle this by differencing, but could not come up with anything that works for unknown $N$.

ARIMA won't be much help, since it deals with seasonality by seasonal differencing, which is very hard to extend to multiple seasonalities. This tag wiki contains pointers to resources for dealing with multiple seasonalities, but they all presuppose known periodicities. To estimate the period lengths, Fourier analysis is likely the most logical tool. How well this works will depend (a) how strong the uplift from $X_{i2}$ is, and (b) on how much data you have.

Both the OP and the first comment seem to ignore the fact that differencing is often unwarranted for time series that are not integrated. What differencing does in such cases is introduce a unit-root moving average component and thus causes more problems than it solves. Also, (S)ARIMA can definitely deal with seasonality without differencing. After all, we have (S)ARIMA(p,d,q,)(P,D,Q) where P and Q may be nonzero even if D is zero!

@StephanKolassa There is only one seasonality $N_i$ for the actual data. It is just not known.

@RichardHardy Differencing was only one strategy I tried. Any other methods are most welcome. Can Seasonal ARIMA handle unknown seasonality?

@dexter04, I have not thought this through, but my intuition is that ARIMA will not handle your type of seasonality.
